# Best way to clean pogo pin connectors

Tags: connector, cleaning

What's the best way to clean pogo pin connectors?

In particular, I've been having recurring problems with the pogo pin connector on the keyboard of an HP Spectre X2 (an Microsoft Surface clone).  I've been using physical abrasion to restore electrical connection, but the problem recurs quickly, so I'm wondering if I should be using a chemical approach, such as a Deoxit product or something like that.  Does anyone have some wisdom to share?

Comment: "Physical abrasion" is probably the worst you can do for a contact, you likely have destroyed the entire oxide-resistant plating. Now only a replacement will help you.

Comment: Ok, unfortunately that makes a lot of sense.  It was completely dysfunctional until I rubbed it so I guess I didn't lose much.

Comment: Just out of curiosity.  What should I have done instead of using abrasion the first time it malfunctioned?  Should I have used a chemical cleaner that preserved the plating?  If so, what sort of product?

Comment: Isopropyl Alcohol